# Rails - 2 models in one view (of model that belongs_to another)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, view, associations

There were several questions and answers for this, except that every time the model view used the opposite of what I need.
In my case, I have 3 models that I want to display in one View.
`Post belongs_to Username`, `Username has_many Posts`. The third model I have is `Category has_many Posts`, which displays correctly through collection select.
The view is of Post model, _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :equipment %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :equipment %><br />
  <%= f.label 'Serial number' %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :serial_num %><br />
  <%= f.label :category %><br />
  <%= collection_select(:post, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>

  <%= f.fields_for :usernames do |user| %>
    <%= user.label :username %><br />
    <%= user.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

That is what I want to do - to display username.name (in post I have FK username_id). The above code `fields_for` doesn't work, it displays nothing.
All the answers on this question that I found are in the view of `has_many` model, while I need this in the view of `belongs_to` model. So, how can I access name attribute of Username model that has_many Posts in post view? (So far I can only access foreign key, which is in Post model).

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :equipment, :serial_num, :username_id
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :username
  validates :username_id, :presence => true
end
```

username.rb

```
class Username < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :posts
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :usernames
resources :categories
resources :posts
```

Please help!

Comment: try `f.fields_for :username`

Comment: First, I had an error which I corrected (it's correct in the code I wrote above) and I changed to :username as you suggest. Now it gives me error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: username"

Answer (score 0):

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :username
```

in your post.rb

But don't you want the post to automatically be assigned to the current_user?????